# Exporting list using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to extract lat/lon values in GEE and I found the following code on stack exchange which does the job. However, when I try to print the lat/ lon values in GEE, it starts to crash. I am going to take a guess here and say it most likely because there is a large number of values ( I could be wrong). Therefore I am trying to export the lists (var point_list in this instance) into a csv, but not quite sure to go on doing that.

Any ideas?

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
              .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
              .first()
var ROI = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
[[[-98.32711839622601,43.77454409032633],
  [-98.32711839622601,43.296678036299085],
  [-97.40426683372601,43.3126679077047],
  [-97.44821214622601,43.80626716084386],
  [-98.32711839622601,43.77454409032633]]]

var image_clipped = dataset.clip(ROI)

var proj = image_clipped.select('cropland').projection()

var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(proj)

var coords = latlon.select(['longitude','latitude']).reduceRegion({
             reducer:ee.Reducer.toList(),
             geometry:ROI
             })

var lat = ee.List(coords.get('latitude'))
var lon = ee.List(coords.get('longitude'))

var point_list = lon.zip(lat)

var coords = cropLandcover.pixelLonLat()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common technique in Earth Engine to export things like lists, values etc which are too large is to first create a feature collection from them and then export them. The feature collection need not have any geometry, so you can create features with empty geometry with the values of interest as properties.

In your case, the following snippet does the trick

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(point_list.map(function(point) {
  return ee.Feature(null, {'value': point})
}))
```

Then you can export `fc` to get the output as CSV

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ce57a9662fc76c726f70d01b1c01a974